# How to renew expired salesforce token for making REST queries

Tags: rest-api, rest, connected-apps

Last night I fetched some data using the below GET request

```
const result = await axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: `https://tahina-test2-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v48.0/query?q=SELECT+Product2Id,+Product2.Name+from+Pricebookentry+WHERE+Pricebook2Id='01s2X000002X6PxQAK'`,
            headers: {
                Authorization:
                    'Bearer 00D2X000001esWS!ASAAQG1hpJDqk71EfwEsDjQEOIVpxLK6B86D8g3yhU5tlUWBtcHoZhpbCtu.kinCTNz03pmHu4xgE_WN05YihmiORJ8e01tZ'
            }
        });
```

But today I cannot fetch the same data as last night as token has expired. So my question is, is there anyway I can keep the token from expiring or getting a new token everytime it expires from my web app? I am using React JS to make this Get call if it helps.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Web Server OAuth Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&type=5), and include the [`refresh_token` scope](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_provider_addl_params_scope.htm&type=5). When your access token expires, you use the [Refresh Token FLow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_refresh_token_flow.htm&type=5) to get a new session. Use this only when you get a 403 error, rather than calling it every time you need to make an API call.

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate. I had to make a small directional change. I am not using JSforce to connect and query SF data into my react app. For this I am using node express on the backend and ran into an issue. Could you maybe help me out here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/311510/jsforce-not-working-on-express? :)